# shortcode en plugin de wordpress

Tags: wordpress-plugin

Estoy intentando generar un shortcode en un plugin para poder reutilizarlo en otras páginas.
El problema es que no hace nada. Intento pasar la estructura y el código:
dentro de la carpeta de plugin, tengo una con el mio con el nombre cookies_mias; a su vez, en esa carpeta, hay un archivo, cookies_mias.php y otra carpeta con nombre includes. El código de  cookies_mias.php:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Mis Cookies
 * Description: Mensaje de aviso de cookies personalizable y responsive
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: 
 * Author URI: /
 * Domain Path: /lang
 */

// Include mfp-functions.php, use require_once to stop the script if mf-functions.php is not found
require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/mias_miscookies.php';
 
?>
```

Dentro de includes:
archivo mias_cookies.php

```html
<?php
/*

Plugin Name:Mis Cookies
Description: This plugin creates an admin sub-menu in existing menu
Version: 1.0
Author: 
Author URI:

*/

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'oaf_create_submenu');

function oaf_create_submenu() {

 add_management_page( 'Mis Cookies', 'Mis Cookies', 'manage_options', 'oaf_create_submenu_plugin', 'oaf_create_submenu_function');

}

function oaf_create_submenu_function () {

 require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'mi_shortcode.php';
}

?>
```

con ello creo una pestalla en el menú de wordpress, detro de herramientas
y por último, mi_shortcode.php

```html
<?php 
function shortcode_personalizado() {
return '<p>Prueba supera</p>';
}
add_shortcode('micodigo', 'shortcode_personalizado');
?>
```

Cuando en cualquiera de mis páginas escribo [micodigo], me escribe exáctamente lo mismo pero no el shortcode que necesito.
Me pueden decir qué estoy haciendo mal? agradecería mucho su ayuda.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Te has asegurado de que llama sin problemas a los archivos? Y en wordpress, no cierres las etiquetas de php al final del archivo, tienden a causar problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La llamada a `mi_shortcode.php` deberías hacerla desde `functions.php` que es el script principal de Wordpress para funciones generales.

Actualmente, al llamarlo desde dentro de una función, todo lo que incluyes se queda dentro del [ámbito](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php) de esa función.(*)

Con esto ya te debería funcionar el `shortcode`.

Aunque nunca he usado `add_management_page()` creo que lo tienes mal planteado, según la [documentacion oficial](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_management_page/) los parámetros son:

> ### Parameters
>
> **$page_title**  (string) (Required):  The text to be displayed in the title tags of the page when the menu is selected.
>
> **$menu_title** (string) (Required): The text to be used for the menu.
>
> **$capability** (string) (Required): The capability required for this menu to be displayed to the user.
>
> **$menu_slug** (string) (Required): The slug name to refer to this menu by (should be unique for this menu).
>
> **$function** (callable) (Optional): The function to be called to output the content for this page. Default value: ''

Por lo tanto en tu código debería ser algo como:

```
<?php
/*

Plugin Name:Mis Cookies
Description: This plugin creates an admin sub-menu in existing menu
Version: 1.0
Author: 
Author URI:

*/

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'oaf_create_submenu');

function oaf_create_submenu() {

    add_management_page( 'Mis Cookies', 'Mis Cookies', 'manage_options', 'oaf_create_submenu_plugin', 'oaf_create_submenu_function');

}
function oaf_create_submenu_function(){
  echo 'Hola, soy el contenido del menú personalizado';
}
```

En `oaf_create_submenu_function()` debes poner el `HTML` que se mostrará en la página, lógicamente podrás usar `include`, pero no para definir funciones de ámbito global.

---

(*)(Editado)

> **ACLARACION**
>
> El ámbito de las variables no tiene nada que ver con el
> ámbito de una función: Todas las funciones (no confundir con los
> métodos de una clase) y clases de PHP tienen ámbito global. Se pueden
> llamar desde fuera de una función incluso si fueron definidas dentro,
> y viceversa.
>
> Fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/functions.user-defined.php
>
> **Aportado por el usuario [Xerif](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/38103/xerif) [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/244617/107208)**

Comment: Muchas gracias. Creo que algo he avanzado. Ahora mi problema es que tengo  que pasar una variable de un plugin a el functions.php. ¿Cómo lo debo hacer?Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Para eso debes hacer otra pregunta, acepta esta respuesta  si crees que soluciona tu problema y date una vuelta por el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), para ir aprendiendo como funciona este sitio ;) es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok muchas gracias y disculpa mi torpeza