# Funcion añadida dentro de otra -error

Tags: php, wordpress

Hice la siguiente funcion en php para enviar correo con la funcion $wp_new_user_notification_email. Tuve que crear una dentro de otra porque la funcion original no admite 4 parametros.

No se envian los correos, que podria estar mal?
Muchas gracias por adelantado!

```
   add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email','custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

  function nueva ( $url,  $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
     function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email(
    $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
    $key = get_password_reset_key( $user );

    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $message = sprintf(__('Bienvenido,')) . "\r\n\r\n";
   $message = "Tu cuenta:
 " . sprintf(__('%s'), $user->user_email) . "
     <br>
   Para establecer la contraseña:
    " . "\r\n\r\n";


    $enlace1= "". network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "\r\n" . "";

   $message .='<a href= "' . $enlace1 . '" onclick="' . $url . '" >Crear Contraseña</a>'. "\r\n";

 $message .= "Saludos," . "\r\n";

 $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;


 }
return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se ejecuta nada ya que, en el `hook`, haces referencia a la función `custom_wp_new_user_notification_email` la cual está fuera del ámbito general, pues fue declarada dentro de la función `nueva` <strike>y por tanto solo existe dentro de esa función</strike>.

[Información sobre los ámbitos de las variables en php.](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php)

Lo que puedes hacer es obtener el valor para la `url` mediante otro medio, no por parámetros. Podrías usar variables de sesión o almacenado en base de datos.

```
        add_filter('wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3);


        function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email($wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname) {

            $url = $_SESSION['url'];

            $key = get_password_reset_key($user);

            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
            $message = sprintf(__('Bienvenido,')) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message = "Tu cuenta:
                         " . sprintf(__('%s'), $user->user_email) . "
                             <br>
                           Para establecer la contraseña:
                            " . "\r\n\r\n";


            $enlace1 = "" . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "\r\n" . "";

            $message .= '<a href= "' . $enlace1 . '" onclick="' . $url . '" >Crear Contraseña</a>' . "\r\n";

            $message .= "Saludos," . "\r\n";

            $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;

            return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
        }
```

---

(Editado)

> **ACLARACION**
>
> El ámbito de las variables no tiene nada que ver con el
>   ámbito de una función: Todas las funciones (no confundir con los
>   métodos de una clase) y clases de PHP tienen ámbito global. Se pueden
>   llamar desde fuera de una función incluso si fueron definidas dentro,
>   y viceversa.
>
> Fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/functions.user-defined.php
>
> **Aportado por el usuario [Xerif](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/38103/xerif)**

Por lo tanto la llamada a `custom_wp_new_user_notification_email` genera un error porque en ningún momento (anterior a su uso) se ha llamado a `nueva()`, que es donde se define como función.

Puedes verificar este comportamiento con este [ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8523f9e3cf8116bf9fd3ed92772a29c66c5f8a91):

```
<?php
 function func_02($a){
     function func_03($a){
        return 'Funcion 3: '.$a;
    }
   return 'Funcion 2: '.func_03($a).PHP_EOL;
 }

 function func_01($a){
  return 'Funcion 1: '.func_03($a).PHP_EOL;
 }


echo func_02('llamo a la 2').PHP_EOL;
echo func_03('llamo a la 3').PHP_EOL;
echo func_01('llamo a la 1').PHP_EOL;
```

Obtendremos error ante cualquier intento de llamar a `func_01()`, o directamente a `func_03()`, antes de ejecutar `func_02()`.

Se ejecutará sin problemas si se sigue el orden correcto.

Comment: Como nota el ámbito de las variables no tiene nada que ver con el ámbito de una funcion: **Todas las funciones (no confundir con los métodos de una clase) y clases de PHP tienen ámbito global. Se pueden llamar desde fuera de una función incluso si fueron definidas dentro, y viceversa.** http://php.net/manual/es/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: Añadido, gracias @Xerif.

Comment: Gracias por su tiempo! lamentablemente no ha funcionado la funcion escrita,  que podria ser?

Comment: Si yo solo debo hacer referencia a un enlace especifico que esta dentro de una funcion?con eso podría solucionarlo.

Comment: @Jennifer edita la pregunta y añade el nuevo código que has intentado. Si ahora el error es diferente mejor crea una nueva pregunta.